# Trubles displaying images from bing image search API v7

Tags: reactjs, image, search, bing-api

I am new to react and js, and I am working on displaying search results from the Bing web and image search API. Currently, I am able to display web results but I do not know why I cannot display images. I am working with next js to build my web app.

headerOption.js

```
const HeaderOption = ({ Icon, title, showImages, setShowImages, isImage, isSelected }) => {
    const handleClick = () => { 
        setShowImages(isImage);
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={handleClick}
        className={`flex items-center space-x-1 border-b-4 border-transparent hover:text-blue-500 hover:border-blue-500 pb-3 cursor-pointer 
        ${ isSelected && "text-blue-500 border-blue-500" }`}
    >
            <Icon className="h-4" />
            <p className="hidden sm:inline-flex">{title}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default HeaderOption;
```

headerOptions.js

```
const HeaderOptions = ({ showImages, setShowImages }) => {
    return (
              ...
                <HeaderOption Icon={SearchIcon} title="All" showImages={showImages} setShowImages={setShowImages} isImage={false} isSelected={!showImages}/>
                <HeaderOption Icon={PhotographIcon} title='Images' showImages={showImages} setShowImages={setShowImages} isImage={true} isSelected={showImages}/>
            ...
    );
};
```

searchResults.js

```
    return (
           ...
 <div className="lg:flex">
                {showImages &&  
                        <div className="w-full grid grid-cols-4">
                            {(dataImages.value == null ? [] : dataImages.value).map((result, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <div className="seachresult_list" style={{  padding:10, }} key={index}>
                                    <div className="group">
                                    <image src={result.thumbnailUrl} className="rounded-md" alt={result.name}/>
                                    <a href={result.hostPageUrl} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"> 
                                        <image src={result.thumbnailUrl} className="rounded-md" alt={result.name} />
                                    </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                );
                            })}
                            </div>
                }
                {!showImages &&  
                    <div className='max-w-xl mb-8'>
                        {(dataText.value == null ? [] : dataText.value).map((result, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div className="seachresult_list" key={index}>
                                    <div className="group">
                                        <a
                                            href={result.url}
                                            className="text-sm"
                                            rel="noreferrer"
                                        >
                                            {result.displayUrl}
                                        </a>
                                        <a href={result.url} rel="noreferrer">
                                            <h2 className="truncate text-xl text-blue-800 font-medium group-hover:underline">
                                                {result.name}
                                            </h2>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p className={isMobile ? 'line-clamp-6' : 'line-clamp-4'}>{result.snippet}</p>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
                }
...
    );
};
```